# Multiple query's needed?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:
- rooms: info about rooms
- beds: info about each bed in the room (type,...) linked to room with roomID
- allocations: info about number of beds in a room allocated to a group (2 groups in one room is possible)

I want a list with number of beds and number of allocated beds in a room

Samples:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(beds.id) AS beds
FROM rooms 
JOIN beds ON rooms.id=beds.roomID 
WHERE rooms.id='124'
```

gives the number of beds in the room (8).

```
SELECT
SUM(requestsAllocations.bedsAllocated) AS allocated,
from rooms 
join requestsAllocations on requestsAllocations.roomID=rooms.id
where rooms.id='124'
```

gives me the number of allocated beds in the room: 7 (1+6)

```
SELECT
COUNT(beds.id) AS beds,
SUM(requestsAllocations.bedsAllocated) AS allocated
FROM rooms 
JOIN requestsAllocations ON requestsAllocations.roomID=rooms.id
JOIN beds ON rooms.id=beds.roomID
WHERE rooms.id='124'
```

gives me:

```
beds | allocated
----------------
16   | 56
```

- 16 beds (count twice because of 2 records in allocation table)
- 56 allocated beds (7*8=56)

How can I make a query to get correct results?

```
beds | allocated
----------------
8    | 7
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct number of beds, you can just add a distinct to your `count`

```
COUNT(distinct beds.id) AS beds
```

To avoid that multiplication of the allocated beds, you can use a workaround like

```
SUM(requestsAllocations.bedsAllocated) / COUNT(distinct beds.id) as allocated
```

The final query would be

```
SELECT  COUNT(distinct t3.id) AS beds,
        SUM(t2.bedsAllocated) / COUNT(distinct t3.id) AS allocated
FROM    rooms t1
JOIN    requestsAllocations t2
ON      t2.roomID = t1.id
JOIN    beds t3
ON      t1.id = t3.roomID
WHERE   t1.id='124'
```

I also gave aliases to your tables to improve readability

Answer (score 0):

You have to do at least one of the aggregations (either the `count` or the `sum`) in a subquery, so that the duplicate records do not affect the aggregated results. Or you can simply aggregate in two correlated subqueries in the select list:

```
select rooms.id,
       (select count(*) from beds where beds.roomID=rooms.id) as bed_count,
       (select sum(bedsAllocated) from requestsAllocations where requestsAllocations.roomID=rooms.id) as allocated_count
from rooms
```